# Why can't I add type constraints when implementing a module type?

Tags: ocaml, type-constraints

I was trying (just out of interest) to do this:

```
module type CAT = sig
  type ('a, 'b) t
  val id : ('a, 'a) t
  val (@) : ('b, 'c) t -> ('a, 'b) t -> ('a, 'c) t
end

module Lst = struct
  type ('a, 'b) t = 'a list constraint 'a = 'b
  let id = []
  let (@) = (@)
end

module L : CAT = Lst (* (error) *)
```

But I get:

```
   Type declarations do not match:
     type ('b, 'a) t = 'b list constraint 'a = 'b
   is not included in
     type ('a, 'b) t
```

Why isn't this safe? Everything that can see the concrete type can also see the constraint, so I don't think you could make something with a wrong type (e.g. call `@` with a `(string, int) t` argument).

---

Update: to those saying that my module doesn't implement the signature because it requires the types to be the same, consider that the following (which just wraps the lists in a List variant) is accepted despite having the same behaviour:

```
module Lst = struct
  type ('a, 'b) t =
    List : 'a list  -> ('a, 'a) t

  let id = List []
  let (@) (type a) (type b) (type c) (a:(b, c) t) (b:(a, b) t) : (a, c) t =
    match a, b with
    | List a, List b -> List (a @ b)
end
```

Comment: See my comment under Jeffrey's answer as for why the second example does _not_ have the same behaviour as the first. In short, you seem to be confusing type well-formedness with type inhabitance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example can be reduced to the type definition alone:

```
module type S =
sig
  type ('a, 'b) t
end

module M =
struct
  type ('a, 'b) t = 'a list constraint 'a = 'b
end
```

As Jeffrey already pointed out, `M` is not of type `S`, because it allows fewer applications of `t`: according to signature `S`, the type `(int, string) t` would be perfectly legal (it is *well-formed*), but `M` does not allow this type (`(int, string) M.t` is not a legal type, because it violates the explicit constraint).

All that is completely independent from the question whether the type is actually *inhabited*, i.e., whether you can construct values of the type. In your second example, the module makes the respective type well-formed, though it is uninhabited. Uninhabited types are legal, however, and sometimes even useful (see e.g. the concept of phantom types).

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't understood before that `constraint` limited what types could be formed, not just what values were possible, but that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 5):

The type signature `CAT` is more general than the type of the `Lst` module. You need to put the type constraint on the abstract type too, i.e. `type ('a, 'b) t constraint 'a = 'b`.

This gives us the following:

```
module type CAT = sig
  type ('a, 'b) t constraint 'a = 'b
  val id : ('a, 'a) t
  val (@) : ('b, 'c) t -> ('a, 'b) t -> ('a, 'c) t
end
```

which is printed as follows by the toplevel, showing a single type variable in the signature of `(@)`:

```
module type CAT = 
  sig
    type ('b, 'a) t constraint 'a = 'b                                          
    val id : ('a, 'a) t
    val ( @ ) : ('c, 'c) t -> ('c, 'c) t -> ('c, 'c) t
  end
```

Error messages of the form "type x is not included in type y" refer to types or module types as specifications of sets of possible values, hence the use of the term "included".

In the case of a module implementation (`Lst`), we have a module type for it. Applying a signature (module type `CAT`) to a module is only allowed if that signature is as specialized (equal set) or more specialized (strict subset) than the original signature of the module.

One can write `module X : sig val f : unit -> unit end = struct let f x = x end`
but not `module X : sig val f : 'a -> 'a end = struct let f () = () end`. The latter gives the following error:

```
Error: Signature mismatch:
       Modules do not match:
       sig val f : unit -> unit end                                           
       is not included in
         sig val f : 'a -> 'a end
       Values do not match:
         val f : unit -> unit
       is not included in
         val f : 'a -> 'a
```

This is different than placing type constraints on certain expressions, in which case the constraint is a mask to be applied (a set to intersect with) rather than a subset. For example it is fine to write `let f : unit -> 'a = fun x -> x` even though `f`'s signature ends up being `unit -> unit`, a strict subset - or subtype - of `unit -> 'a`.

Comment: But in your example, your module really can't handle e.g. `f 3` so the error is correct. But my `@` can handle every possible `('a, 'b) Lst.t`. I've added a further example to the question, showing that it's not necessary to limit the `CAT` type to create a `Lst` module with the same behaviour (though with a less efficient implementation).

Comment: Every possible `('a, 'b) Lst.t` is really just every possible `('a, 'a) Lst.t` because of the type constraint `'a = 'b`. Try this: `type ('a, 'b) t = unit constraint 'a = 'b` and then `type t' = (int, string) t`. You get the error "This type string should be an instance of type int".

Answer (score 3):

Your `Lst` module doesn't seem to me to have the type `CAT`. `CAT` allows the two types `'a` and `'b` to be independent. The `Lst` module requires them to be the same. If the `L` module were of type `CAT` then it should allow me to make something of type `(string, int) t` but it doesn't.

The error message is a little confusing, at least to me.

Comment: I don't see why the signature implies you should be able to make arbitrary types. For example, if the signature defines `type 'a t` and the module defines `type 'a t = Int : int -> int t` then OCaml is happy, even though you can't make a `string t`.

Comment: @ThomasLeonard, that's incorrect, you can make a `string t` just fine. That type doesn't have any values inhabiting it, but that doesn't mean it's an invalid type. Jeffrey's reply is spot on.

Comment: What code would you use to "make a `string t`" then? (e.g. like you would "make a `string list`" with `["foo"]`). If a type is uninhabited then you can't make values of that type, by definition. Note that I've added another example to the question, which has the same type and behaviour as my code and *is* accepted by OCaml.

Comment: @ThomasLeonard, I thought you meant that you cannot _form_ the type `string t`. But you can. You cannot construct values, but that doesn't make it an ill-formed type. Similarly, your second example does _not_ have the same "behaviour" as the first: with the second example, `(int, string) t` is a legal type, with the first it is not. That's regardless of whether it is inhabited. Type well-formedness and inhabitedness are separate properties (and sometimes uninhabited types are useful, cf. phantom types).

Comment: OK, I see my "make arbitrary types" was confusing. I meant "making values of arbitrary types", which I think is what Jeffrey meant. Your distinction of "legal" types sounds important. Do you want to add a separate answer? It would be really useful to see an example of how the compiler accepting my first example would lead to incorrect behaviour at runtime.

Comment: Done. I'm not sure how to answer to your question about incorrect runtime behaviour, though. That is not the issue here. The issue is that a constraint explicitly restricts the legality of certain type applications, by choice of the programmer. If the first example was allowed, such a constraint could easily be undermined (because `(int, string) L.t` would be legal) and thus be entirely meaningless.